# I want to replace single quotes with double quotes in a list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

So I am making a program that takes a text file, breaks it into words, then writes the list to a new text file.

The issue I am having is I need the strings in the list to be with double quotes not single quotes.

For example

I get this `['dog','cat','fish']` when I want this `["dog","cat","fish"]`

Here is my code

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
nonewline = []
for x in file:
    nonewline.append(x[:-1])
words = []
for x in nonewline:
    words = words + x.split()
textfile = open('output.txt','w')
textfile.write(str(words))
```

I am new to python and haven't found anything about this.
Anyone know how to solve this?

[Edit: I forgot to mention that i was using the output in an arduino project that required the list to have double quotes.]

Comment: ['dog','cat','fish']  is the same as [dog,cat,fish] the quotes are just to sinalize the string. The quotes are not part of the string. Try print(words[0]) and you will understand

Comment: "The issue I am having is I need the strings in the list to be with double quotes not single quotes." - why? What are you going to do with this file that requires double quotes? Are you trying to output JSON or something? (If so, there's a [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for that.)

Comment: Please show the input file.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You cannot change how `str` works for `list`.

How about using [JSON format](http://json.org/) which use `"` for strings.

```
>>> animals = ['dog','cat','fish']
>>> print(str(animals))
['dog', 'cat', 'fish']

>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(animals))
["dog", "cat", "fish"]
```

---

```
import json

...

textfile.write(json.dumps(words))
```

Comment: `json.dumps('dog')` ouputs `'"dog"'` to the file but I want `"dog"`. How to do that?

Comment: @chandresh, print it. surrounding single quotes are there to represent the object is string. (That's how the `repr` represent). If you print it (or write it to file, ...), you will get what you want.

Comment: @falsetru I did that and only after that I posted my comment above. Can you check once again?

Comment: @chandresh, could you post a separate question and let me know the url of the question. It's hard to know what's the problem without reproducible code.

Comment: @falsetru [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677524/replace-single-quoted-sting-to-double-quoted-string-in-python)

Comment: @falsetru I'm not the author of that question, I just commented on it earlier, found that it linked to here and saw your comment. (But it's been closed now anyway)

Comment: @mkrieger1, Ah. Sorry, I should mention the  chandresh, not you. my apologies.

Comment: @chandresh, Your new question post does not involve reproducible code. Please post with code that can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 43):

Most likely you'll want to just replace the single quotes with double quotes in your output by replacing them:

```
str(words).replace("'", '"')
```

You *could* also extend Python's `str` type and wrap your strings with the new type changing the `__repr__()` method to use double quotes instead of single. It's better to be simpler and more explicit with the code above, though.

```
class str2(str):
    def __repr__(self):
        # Allow str.__repr__() to do the hard work, then
        # remove the outer two characters, single quotes,
        # and replace them with double quotes.
        return ''.join(('"', super().__repr__()[1:-1], '"'))

>>> "apple"
'apple'
>>> class str2(str):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return ''.join(('"', super().__repr__()[1:-1], '"'))
...
>>> str2("apple")
"apple"
>>> str2('apple')
"apple"
```