# Removing single quotes from a list of string

Tags: python, json

I have a list of products which are strings & want to remove single quotes from it

The list of products retrieved from a sql query in python environment

`['000003286694', '000003286704', '000003420412']`

I have to pass this list as a payload to json object. So it needs to be preceded by double quotes.

I have used following method 
`d=[('"'+i+'"') for i in x]`

but I get the output as
`['"000003286694"', '"000003286704"', '"000003420412"']`

I tried using regex, replace method to get away with single quotes but no success.
Can anyone please share workaround for this

I want result list should be 
`["000003286694", "000003286704", "000003420412"]`

Comment: You already have a solution here ->https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183505/7841468

Answer (score 0):

```
    data =['000003286694', '000003286704', '000003420412']
    import json
    result =json.dumps(data)
    print(result)  #["000003286694", "000003286704", "000003420412"]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Using json.dumps will make result as string. I need to use this as a list